# rsync running differently from QProcess compared to bash command line

Tags: c++, qt, rsync, qprocess

I am experimenting with launching rsync from QProcess and although it runs, it behaves differently when run from QProcess compared to running the exact same command from the command line.

Here is the command and stdout when run from QProcess

```
/usr/bin/rsync -atv --stats --progress --port=873 --compress-level=9 --recursive --delete --exclude="/etc/*.conf" --exclude="A*" rsync://myhost.com/haast/tmp/mysync/* /tmp/mysync/

receiving incremental file list
created directory /tmp/mysync
A
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=6/7)
B
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=5/7)
test.conf
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=4/7)
subdir/
subdir/A2
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=2/7)
subdir/C
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#5, to-check=1/7)
subdir/D
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#6, to-check=0/7)

Number of files: 7
Number of files transferred: 6
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 105
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 174
Total bytes received: 367

sent 174 bytes  received 367 bytes  360.67 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Notice that although I excluded 'A*', it still copied them!  Now running the exact same command from the command line:

```
/usr/bin/rsync -atv --stats --progress --port=873 --compress-level=9 --recursive --delete --exclude="/etc/*.conf" --exclude="A*" rsync://myhost.com/haast/tmp/mysync/* /tmp/mysync/
receiving incremental file list
created directory /tmp/mysync
B
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=4/5)
test.conf
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=3/5)
subdir/
subdir/C
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=1/5)
subdir/D
           0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=0/5)

Number of files: 5
Number of files transferred: 4
Total file size: 0 bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 83
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 132
Total bytes received: 273

sent 132 bytes  received 273 bytes  270.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Notice that now the 'A*' exclude is respected!  Can someone explain why they are performing differently?

A noticed that if I removed the quotes surrounding the excludes, then the QProcess run performs correctly.

Comment: probably directory is related to working dir and it is different in these 2 cases?

Comment: But why would it work if I remove the quotes from the --exclude values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command-line execution, bash interpreter performs a previous substitution and remove quotes, so they are not passed to rsync arg list.

Next script shows how bash substitution is performed:

```
[tmp]$ cat printargs.sh 
#!/bin/bash
echo $*
[tmp]$ ./printargs.sh --exclude="A*"
--exclude=A*
```

Comment: Why do people bother with quotes if it works without them ?